# Phonegap android black external image

Tags: android, html, cordova

I'm new to android/phonegap development. I'm trying to access external images but I only get black places where the image should be on the emulator.If I try to open the html in chrome it displays the image. I already added the domain to the white list.

Would you be so kind as to help me figure out what the problem could be?

Thank you,

Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an error of the emulator, when I tried on an actual device all worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the case of the images names. See if the browser is also displaying the image or not

Comment: The image name is correct and the image is displayed in the browser but the emulator...

Comment: are you using ripple?

Comment: I'm using the default emulator came with the android sdk

Comment: try to package the app and run on the phone or show some code to help you out